# Hiding the text box when clicking the button in the asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button in my asp.net web application. When i clicking the button it will hide the text box in the same webs  application .
If is it possible that anyone help me its very useful
Thank you

Comment: check the event handler for the button onclick, can u pass the code-behind here?

Comment: do you want to hide from code behind

Comment: Do the google first before asking question..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from code behind  `TextBoxId.Visible = false;`

from Javascript `document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxId.ClientId%>').style.dispaly="none";`

Answer (score 2):

If the button is an html button then you can use javascript to do this:

onclick of button call following js:

```
document.getElementById(textBoxId).style.display = "none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById(textBoxId).style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: because on server side code behind textbox visible property is still true

Comment: @Pranay: When we do this textbox will serve as hidden field and after submit if we post back it will be in it's initial state which is most likely to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JQuery:

```
<script>
    $("#myButton").click(function () {
      $("#myTextBox").hide("slow");
    });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

**HideTextBox.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HideTextBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="HideTextFields" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnHide" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Hide TextBox" />   
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind file
**HideTextBox.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class HideTextFields : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in form1.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
                c.Visible = false;

        }
    }
}
```